# How to modify Pre-loaded data in ODK (Open data kit)

Tags: xml, odk

How do I modify preloaded data in Open Data Kit?

Please could you explain with an XML example. I am having difficulty modifying data which is preloaded.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an outline of the *actual* problem you're facing along with what you've tried. Try to adhere to the guidelines laid out here when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you are trying to modify preloaded data (i.e. references in as `<instance>` with a `src` attribute, that's not possible. External instances are readonly. So you'd have to have some mechanism where your primary instance (submission) updates the external data file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to edit data in xml. Best way to edit data is, once you export data on the server or in CSV file then with the help of statical tools like Excel, R, Python, SPSS, Stata etc. you can edit the data. 
This is the best way to editing data and this calls Data Cleaning.

Narendra